# Referenciar un Control Java con un String

Tags: java

Tengo un `array` de cadena con los nombres de unos controles `Label` y quiero referenciarlos por dicho nombre. O lo que es lo mismo, quiero pasar un `String` a un control `Label`. Por ejemplo, en VBA sería así:

```
for i=0 to 10
 formulario.Controls(miarray(i)).setcaption = "" 
next i
```

Pero, ¿cómo lo hago en Java?

Comment: quiero poner el nombre de un control según el contenido de un array. Por ejemplo `mirarray[i].setText="";`

Comment: No entiendo exactamente tu pregunta. ¿Tienes unas labels a las cuales quieres asignarle un texto que se encuentra dentro de un array? ¿Podrías añadir el código que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: El array contiene los nombres de los controles. En vez de hacer `control1.setText=""`quiero hacer `miarray[1].setText=""`

Comment: Si la clase de control1 tiene un campo publico `setText`, el código por que preguntas funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para lograr dicho propósito, es necesario obtener los  [Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) que posee tu [Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) , Como solo se desea manipular los  `JLabel` tendrías que verificar que el Componente sea de tipo `JLabel` , esto se realiza mediante el operador  `instanceof` , sí esto se cumple tocaría validar que el nombre del componente esté dentro de tu `Array` de Nombres.

```
String [] nombres = new String[]{"label1","label4","label3"}; /* Array de Nombres*/
Component[] componentes = JFrame.getContentPane().getComponents();/* Obtenemos 
                                                                   los componentes*/
  for (int i=0; i < componentes.length; i++) {
     if (componentes[i] instanceof JLabel) { /* Verificamos el Tipo de Componente*/
        /* Verificamos si el nombre existe en el Arreglo de Nombres*/
         boolean x = Arrays.asList(nombres).contains(componentes[i].getName());
         /* Si Existe entonces aplicas los cambios necesarios ,
            en este caso se cambio el Texto */
         if(x)((JLabel)componentes[i]).setText("Nuevo Texto");
      }
 }
```