# ¿Cómo llamar a un objeto sin variable de referencia?

Tags: java

Tengo una pequeña inquietud con java en un sentido, hay veces que uno instancia un objeto en los parámetros de otro método, Ej:

```
add(new JButton("Hello"));
```

La pregunta es como llamar a el botón que esta en los parámetros de ese método , ¿Se puede? ¿Cómo?.

Comment: Si lo estás agregando a un contenedor como `JFrame` o `JPanel` Puedes revisar esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59731/referenciar-un-control-java-con-un-string/59743#59743) , pero en lugar de `JLabel` sería un `JButton` en la validación. si no la única otra opción que puedas acceder a el es agregando a  un Lista como menciona Dacoso

Answer (score 4):

A menos que cuando le das `.add(new JButton("Nuevo"));` lo estes agregando a una collection o ArrayList ahi si lo puedes recuperar por medio del texto que le has dado en los parentesis y este solo estara disponible en tiempo de ejecucion.
Recuerda si los vas a utilizar iterarlo y asignarle un ActionListener

```
for (JButton button: miArrayDeBotones){
   JButton boton = (JButton) button;
   if(boton.getText.equals("Nuevo")){
      System.out.println("Tal cosa");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton btn = new JButton("hello");

add(btn);
```

Después usar lo que usted quiera con la variable `btn`.

Answer (score 1):

En terminos generales, la respuesta es no.

Si instancias objetos directamente en la llamada a un metodo no tienes ninguna referencia al objeto. La referencia existe solo en el cuerpo del metodo llamado como parametro.

```
void add(Object o){
    //hacer algo con o
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
¿Si no tienes una referencia como puedes llamar algo específicamente?
```

De la forma como lo realizas la única referencia sería el texto que le asignas:

```
add(new JButton("Hello"));
```

De otra forma la referencia podría ser el por ejemplo el nombre o el id, para poder usar ese botón tienes que crear una variable

```
JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
add(button);
```